# How do you call methods into an object array?

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods, call

I have two classes. A class called Cat, that holds the cat names, birth year and weight in kilos. I have a class called Cattery that is an array. I want to input cats from the Cat class into the array. Each cat will have its own name, birth year and weight in Kilos. How do I do this? Thank you.

```
public class Cat {

    private String name;
    private int birthYear;
    private double weightInKilos;

/**
 * default constructor
 */ 
public Cat() {   
}

/**
 * @param name
 * @param birthYear
 * @param weightInKilos
 */
public Cat(String name, int birthYear, double weightInKilos){   
    this.name = name;
    this.birthYear = birthYear;
    this.weightInKilos = weightInKilo
}

/**
 * @return the name.
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @return the birthYear.
 */
public int getBirthYear() {
    return birthYear;
}

/**
 * @return the weightInKilos.
 */  
public double getWeightInKilos() {
    return weightInKilos;
}

/**
 * @param the name variable.
 */
public void setName(String newName) {
    name = newName; 
}

/**
 * @param the birthYear variable.
 */
public void setBirthYear(int newBirthYear) {
    birthYear = newBirthYear;
}

/**
 * @param the weightInKilos variable.
 */
public void setWeightInKilos(double newWeightInKilos) {
    weightInKilos = newWeightInKilos;
} 
}
```

The array class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Cattery {

    private ArrayList<Cat> cats;
    private String businessName;

/**
 * @param Cattery for the Cattery field.
 */

public Cattery() {
    cats = new ArrayList<Cat>();
    this.businessName = businessName;
}

/**
 * Add a cat to the cattery.
 * @param catName the cat to be added.
 */
public void addCat(Cat name)
{
    Cat.add(getName());
}

/**
 * @return the number of cats.
 */
public int getNumberOfCats()
{
    return cats.size();
}
}
```

Comment: Try calling "here kitty", though tapping its food bowl may work better :-).

Comment: Call `cats.add(new Cat(...))`?

Answer (score 1):

just edit the "addCat" method to pass object from argument to your ArrayList.

```
public void addCat(Cat name)
{
    cats.add(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you are trying to do is add cats to the `cats` list you declared in your `Cattery`.  Another answer already notes the correction needed - your `addCat` method must be modified then to actually put the cats in the list.  Note that you're not adding the cat name, but an actual `Cat` object.  It also seems like you want the `Cattery` to have a business name.  You can pass that in to the constructor.

```
public Cattery(String businessName) {
    cats = new ArrayList<Cat>();
    this.businessName = businessName;
}
...
public void addCat(Cat cat)
{
    cats.add(cat);
}
```

Here's an example of how you may create your cattery and subsequently add cats.  You must love cats.

```
class CatApp{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cattery cattery = new Cattery("The Delicious Cats Business");
        cattery.addCat(New Cat("Milo", 3, 388.87));
        cattery.addCat(New Cat("Otis", 2, 1.4));
        System.out.println("Total number of cats ready for consumption = " 
            + cattery.getNumberOfCats());
    }
}
```

Comment: @ajb Milo is a gluttonous cat.

Comment: I'm more worried about the number of cats *"ready for consumption"*.  Do you regularly **eat** cats ???

Comment: @StephenC You mean you have never had cat? :P